# valor del mapa se actualiza antes de evaluar condición

Tags: java, java-8, recursión, hashmap

Reformulo la pregunta que he hecho hace un momento. Estoy realizando un método el cual va añadiendo nuevos tipos a un almacén. La idea es llevar a cabo el método x veces hasta que el valor que paso como parámetro `resultado` después de realizar una iteración y actualizarlo, sea igual a su valor antes de la última iteración `res0` y entonces devolver dicho resultado. Mientras que sea distinto, pues llamo recursivamente.

```
   public HashMap<String, List<String>> calcularTipoNoprimitivo2(HashMap<String,List<String>> resultado) {
    HashMap<String,List<String>> res0 =new HashMap<>();   //creo el hashmap quue contendra 'resultado' de la iteracion anterior
    res0 = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) resultado.clone();  //lo clono para que tenga el resultado antes de la iteracion

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> dicIni : almacen_inicializaciones.entrySet()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<List<String>>> diccTipos : almacen_tipos.entrySet()) {
            List<List<String>> cuerpoTipoNoPrimitivo;
            cuerpoTipoNoPrimitivo = almacen_tipos.get(diccTipos.getKey());
            if (!cuerpoTipoNoPrimitivo.isEmpty()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < cuerpoTipoNoPrimitivo.size(); i++) {
                    List<String> sublista;
                    sublista = cuerpoTipoNoPrimitivo.get(i);
                    if (dicIni.getValue().containsAll(sublista)) {    //si la entrada contiene a todos los valores de sublista entonces
                        List<String> listaAux = new ArrayList<>();   //creo listaAux que contendra el nuevo tipo que quiero introducir
                        listaAux = dicIni.getValue();               // extraigo  la antigua definicion
                        listaAux.add(diccTipos.getKey());            //añado a listaAux el nuevo tipo. Aquí es cuando el metodo falla y actualiza automaticamente el valor en 'resultado' y en el clon, 'res0'
                        if (!resultado.containsValue(listaAux)) {    // no llega a evaluar la condicion
                            resultado.put(dicIni.getKey(), listaAux);
                        }
                         if(!almacen_inicializaciones.containsValue(listaAux)){
                            almacen_inicializaciones.put(dicIni.getKey(), listaAux);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!(res0.equals(resultado))) {      //después de la iteracion la idea es compararlos, si son distintos pues llamo recursivamente
        calcularTipoNoprimitivo2(resultado);
    }
    return resultado;                   //si son iguales ppues devuelvo ese resultado
}
```

Los problemas que tengo son, que a la hora de crear el clon de resultado, 'res0' cuando actualizo resultado dentro de la iteración también actualizo el clon, lo cual no entiendo porque son Hashmaps distintos,(o eso indica en su id). Por otra parte, tras llamar recursivamente la primera vez, cuando actualizo listaAux, se actualiza automáticamente el valor tanto en el map de resultado como en res0, sin antes comprobar la condición para ver si efectivamente quiero que se actualice o no.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te pasa lo típico que te crees que estás pasando por valor ( porque en java todo se pasa por valor ) pero java te está troleando porque los objetos no son valores.

Básicamente al hacer clone del array estas clonando el objeto, que a su vez digamos es una referencia, esto es lo que se conoce como "shallow copy". Tú lo que quieres hacer es un "deep copy".

Algún ejemplo:
https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/hashmap/shallow-deep-copy-hashmap/

Por ser algo mas específico, la solución sería en vez de hacer:

```
res0 = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) resultado.clone();
```

Harías algo como (usando SerializationUtils de apache commons):

```
res0 = SerializationUtils.clone(resultado);
```

Comment: no funciona el link, pero le echo un ojo a lo de shalow copy. Para lo de la lista habría alguna solucion? @forlayo

Comment: @juanchi la solución podría ser hacer un deep copy en vez del clone, en el link aparecen ejemplos de todo; lo he vuelto a poner espero que esta vez funcione :D